# Trying to call a function in java, complains ".class expected".

Tags: java, class, function, call

Novice programmer here. trying to learn static methods and recursion. No idea why I keep getting ".class expected" error whenever i try to call "drawCircle()". My code is below. Help plz? Thanks!

```
public class Drawliin
{
    public static void drawCircle(int numberOfTimes, double radius, double center[])
    {
        int rep = 1;
        if (rep == 1)
        {
            StdDraw.circle(center[0], center[1], radius);
            rep++;
        }
        else if (rep <= numberOfTimes)
            {
            StdDraw.circle(center[0 + radius], center[1], radius);
            StdDraw.circle(center[0 - radius], center[1], radius);
            StdDraw.circle(center[0], center[1 + radius], radius);
            StdDraw.circle(center[0], center[1 - radius], radius);
            rep++;
            drawCircle(numberOfTimes, radius, center[]);
            }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        double r = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
        StdDraw.setXscale(-10, 10);
        StdDraw.setYscale(-10, 10);
        double c[] = new double[2];
        drawCircle(N, r, c[]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
drawCircle(N, r, c);
```

You just pass `c`.  You don't need to indicate it's an array again.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is at these lines:

```
drawCircle(N, r, c[]);
drawCircle(numberOfTimes, radius, center[]);
```

they should be:

```
drawCircle(N, r, c);
drawCircle(numberOfTimes, radius, center);
```

You don't need to define it as an array again, you did that in the parameters. Just pass the arguments to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the braces in 'center' and 'c:

```
drawCircle(numberOfTimes, radius, center);

drawCircle(N, r, c);
```